# Symbols instead text when fill pdf forms

Tags: python, pdf, pdftk, pdf-form, fdfgen

I would like to to fill pdf forms of pdf file from website: https://e-justice.europa.eu/content_european_payment_order_forms-156-en.do#action

The file name is Form A - Application for a European order for payment (click on pdf picture).

Lets say I want to fill first two fields using python:

```
from fdfgen import forge_fdf
fields = [('field1','Some text'), ('field2', 'some text')]
fdf = forge_fdf("",fields,[],[],[])
fdf_file = open("data.fdf","wb")
fdf_file.write(fdf)
fdf_file.close()
```

Then I fill my pdf with above data.fdf file:

```
pdftk form.pdf fill_form data.fdf output output.pdf flatten
```

If I then open my pdf I can see symbols (little cubes) instead of text: 
[image]

If I click in the form the text appears, but only if form is active.

Do you know why I get symbols instead text?

Comment: Fixed your `fields` variable, you were missing a `'`.

Comment: Regarding yoru document, I guess your document is encoded with a encoding different to `UTF-8` or `ASCII`. The later probably being your Python default encoding if you're on a older windows machine. Try changing the encoding of your python script and the data you're putting in.

Comment: Torxed, how to figure out encoding of PDF? I am on Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: Coul you please write a code?

Comment: Torxed, I didn't understand which encoding should I use? You said it shouldn't be UTF-8 but which should be?